# What is implied probability, in the context of universal codes?

Tags: information-theory, huffman-coding

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_(data_compression)):

> Each universal code, like each other self-delimiting (prefix) binary
>    code, has its own "implied probability distribution" given by $ p(i)
>  ={2}^{-\ell(i)} $  where $\ell(i)$ is the length of the $i$th codeword and $p(i)$ is the corresponding symbol's probability

What is "implied probability"?

Given that prefix code are not fix-length codes, then I don't get what "implied probability" means, for example, given a 3 bits length code, implied probability is ${2}^{-3} = \frac{1}{8}$ but what does it mean? is it about choosing the code between others? or choosing random between all possible of three bits? as here we are talking about prefix codes, so length will vary among codes, so there could be only one code of three bits, so probability of get it would be 1? Any clarification will help!

Comment: Why isn't it just that when you randomly guess three bits, the chance that they're equal to your three bits is $1/8$?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks because it's a **prefix code**, so there are not 2^8 codes for 3 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is the following:

the following tree $T$

$
\\
\emptyset
\\ 
|   \ \setminus \\
|   \ \ \ \setminus \\
0 \ \ \ \ \   1
\\ 
|   \ \setminus \\
|   \ \ \ \setminus \\
00 \ \ \ \ \   01\\
\\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |   \ \setminus \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |   \ \ \ \setminus \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 010 \ \ \ \ \   011
$

of depth 3 is constructed by

1. Taking an object *labeled as $\emptyset$* that has probability 1 and splitting it in half into two pieces *which we label as $0,1$;* who each acquire equal probabilities 1/2 individually.
2. Taking the object *labeled as $0$* that has probability 1/2 and splitting it in half into two pieces *which we label as $00,01$;* who acquire equal probabilities 1/4 individually.
3. Taking the object *labeled as $01$* that has probability 1/2 and splitting it in half into two pieces *which we label as $010,011$;* who each acquire equal probabilities 1/8 individually.

This is essentially the "unwrapping the Huffman algorithm in reverse." **You are asking the wrong question, you should be asking *"Why label it this way?"***

The idea behind the Huffman coding scheme is that

1. $0,1$ each cost 1 unit of "communication complexity" or "space complexity" depending on your interests
2. $00,01$ each cost 2 units of "communication complexity"
3. $010,011$ each cost 3 units of "communication complexity"

[You should read chapter 5 of Cover and Thomas](https://g.co/kgs/Dkan6W)

and [this Wikipedia article on the kraft inequality is probably helpful too.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality) however, if you want a proof of the infinite kraft inequality you need [chapter 5 of Cover and Thomas](https://g.co/kgs/Dkan6W).

The idea is to continue this (type of) procedure unto infinity so that we get a something the following tree $T_\infty$

$
\\
\emptyset
\\ 
|   \ \setminus \\
|   \ \ \ \setminus \\
0 \ \ \ \ \   1
\\ 
|   \ \setminus \\
|   \ \ \ \setminus \\
00 \ \ \ \ \   01\\
\\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |   \ \setminus \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |   \ \ \ \setminus \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 010 \ \ \ \ \   011 \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |   \ \setminus \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |   \ \ \ \setminus \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots \ \ \ \ \   0101
$

which has infinite depth.  **Each time you "split" a string, you maintain a "partition of unity" *i.e.,* you maintain a probability distribution. The [kraft inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality) states that if your code was constructed in this manner, *i.e.,***
$$
\sum_{i : \text{leaf of }T_\infty} 2^{-l(i)} = 1 
$$
**then the code is optimal.**

> In other words if you have a set of binary strings $\mathcal{S}$ and the function 
>   $$p(s) = 2^{-l(s)}$$
>   turns out to actually satisfy the kraft inequality, *i.e.,* 
>   $$
> \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} 2^{-l(i)} = 1, 
> $$ then it is an optimal code. **Therefore forming a probability distribution and being an optimal code are equivalent.**

One can further prove that all such codes have a tree that witnesses their optimality.

---

Comment: Can you give an particular example of actual coding with that properties? is it necessary to go to infinity to get that properties, is that an assumption/requirement?

Comment: Yea, sure. Suppose that I send you a text message every day and I always send one message from the following set {"hello", "goodbye", "thank you",  "that's cool"} and suppose that p("hello") =1/2, p("goodbye")=1/4, p("thank you")=1/8,  and p("that's cool")=1/8. If I apply the Huffman algorithm to this I will get a tree equivalent to the example I gave, i.e., the code p("hello") =1, p("goodbye")=00, p("thank you")=010,  p("that's cool")=011 is an optimal code. You may check that this code satisfies the Kraft inequality. It is not necessary to go to infinity to get those properties.

Comment: I gave you an infinite example because you posted this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_(data_compression) which led me to believe you wanted to understand some asymptotic property about universal codes. But the Kraft inequality applies to any code, finite or infinite. You can apply it to understanding the Huffman coding scheme or any other coding scheme. The main idea I wanted to leave you with is that the "deeper meaning of the implied probability" is much ado with the optimality of coding schemes as a matter of fact the Kullback–Leibler divergence between the ...

Comment: ... the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence between the implied distribution of the code and the true distribution of the messages you are encoding is a measure of how good or bad your coding scheme is. For example, check out the following links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Relationship_between_models_and_reality  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Relation_to_minimizing_Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence_and_cross_entropy  the following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity is also cool

Comment: Sorry, no, there is cherrypicking in your example, you have chosen symbols probabilities exactly as power of -2, so no surprise in the result. But real probabilities of symbols are independent of coding, particularly don't have to be power of -2, could be 1/3, 1/88, or 1/whatever, so after coding them, you assign prefix codes of a determinate length. Symbol probability for you, Shannon and me, is about source, as in you example it will depend on ratios of hello, goodbye, etc.. we send, not in the encoding.So your example is equating both definitions, my question is exactly about the difference

Comment: Your question states nothing about non-dyadic probability distributions, so I was not cherrypicking. Suppose that p("hello") =4/10, p("goodbye")=+3/10, p("thank you")=2/10, and p("that's cool")=1/10. Huffman's algorithm will stil return a code equivalent to the example I gave, i.e., f("hello") =1, f("goodbye")=00, f("thank you")=010, f("that's cool")=011. It is still the optimal binary code for the distribution. See no cherrypicking buddy. In ch. of 5 of Cover & Thomas they prove that this will always be within 1 bit of the optimum. The difference you are looking for is the KL divergence.

Comment: I linked all of these resources to you. But did you bother reading any of it? No. Chapter 5 also describes using a tree that has a branching factor of any fixed integer size $d$. It is usually called a $d$-ary code. For example for the example I just provided you with a $10$-ary code would have been perfect. The idea is that you really don't gain anything since you will always be within 1 bit of the optimal encoding. Go to theorem 5.4.3 of Cover and Thomas "Elements of Information Theory" 2nd ed. for clarification of your misunderstanding of the "difference" that you are having. Take care!

Comment: Please don't read words as internet fight, was not intended at all. Indeed I do comment your answer because is interesting as it mentions cost units of "communication complexity" relating the length, I know that. Still that's not my question, an extreme example of p("hello")=.9, and p("bye")=.1, with no more words to say, would lead to prefix codes 1 and 00, I get, that 00 would have half of "implied probability" than 1, but that's my question why wikipedia conflated it and said "symbol's probability" when we, as in these comments examples, know that it is not the same as coding probability.

Comment: As in the title of the question it was about universal codes, coding integers, then I still couldn't relate how the symbol probability of any integer, is half of the next coding, more, why all numbers with same encoding have same probability, that detail makes me do the question. As this got long, I understood that the answer is simply a definition the "universal encoding" assumes just that distribution being smaller numbers more probable than bigger, period. But *without that assumption*, I couln't get why the symbol probability is dividing in half every steps the coding grow a bit.

Comment: My apologies for my hostility. The only reasonable interpretation to give to the implied probability is that "If a set of integers, $S$, has the implied probability, then the standard encoding of integers is the optimal one." We could have encoded integers using other symbols but we chose the correspondence that we did, "Under which conditions is this an optimal code? When the probability distribution on $S$ is the implied distribution, that's when." If you try to go any deeper than that, then you are leaving the realm of the intended semantics of the scientists who invented the def. Take care

Comment: Is all right, I think that's what it means, not a result but a definition, that is the missing assumption I mention in the question bounty, thanks. I edit to correct the signs. You could add that meaning to the answer.

Comment: There are other reasons why $2^{l(n)}$ is a good choice for a probability distribution but they leave the current universe of discourse but maybe it will help. Cantor space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space is the set of all infinite binary sequences. We can identify it with the set of all real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$. Every finite sequence is the initial segment of a real number in cantor space and therefore we can identify the intervals $(a_0a_1...a_n000...,a_0a_1...a_n1111... )$ with the finite sequences of the form $a_0....a_n$. If the integer $k = a_0...a_n$ then ...

Comment: If the integer $k = a_0...a_n$ then $\text{measure}(a_0a_1...an000...,a_0a_1...a_n100...) = 2^{l(k)}$. For example cosider the interval $(0.0010,0.00111111...)=(1/8,1/4)$, the measure of $(0.0010,0.00111111...)$ is equal to $1/8$ (since $1/4-1/8=1/8$). We can see that in this sense it is the most natural probability distribution, i.e., the uniform distribution, you can give to the real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$. We have now left the realm of the original discussion; however, it is always nice to witness the beauty and unity of mathematics. See wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with information theory. Suppose we have a random source that outputs symbols with some fixed probability distribution $P$ over an alphabet $X$. Shannon's theory says that any coding scheme must use at least $H(P) = \sum_{x \in X} P(x) \log_2 (1/P(x))$ bits per symbol on average. The value $H(P)$ is called the entropy $P$. A full prefix code is always optimal for *some* distribution $P$, in the sense that it matches the $H(P)$ lower bound. That distribution is called the implied distribution of the code.

For example, suppose we have a prefix-code over the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with code words $a$ = "000", $b$ = "001", $c$ = "01" and $d$ = "1". By your formula, the implied probability distribution is $P(a) = 1/8$, $P(b) = 1/8$ and $P(c) = 1/4$ and $P(d) = 1/2$. The entropy of this distribution is

$$\frac{1}{8} \log 8 + \frac{1}{8} \log 8 + \frac{1}{4} \log 4 + \frac{1}{2} \log 2 = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{3}{8} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{7}{4}$$

The expected length of the code words is the sum of code lengths, each weighted by their probability:

$$
\frac{1}{8} \cdot 3 + \frac{1}{8} \cdot 3 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{7}{4}
$$

This matches the entropy bound, and hence the code is optimal for this distribution.

Comment: So, as I read in your answer "a full prefix code is always optimal for some distribution P", good point, then it seems Universal Codes to be a kind of hypothetical ideal codes that fit that distribution P

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are mis-parsing the phrase 'implied probability distribution'.  There is no such thing as 'implied probability'.  What Wikipedia is saying is: Given a self-delimiting coding scheme, there is an 'obvious' or 'natural' *(here a mathematician would, I suspect, use the term 'canonical')* way to assign numbers to legal codewords, in such a way that the numbers constitute a probability distribution over the set of all legal codewords.  The naturalness of this assignment means that it is not necessary to expend any great mental effort to explicitly construct this distribution, which is why it is 'implied'.

Comment: Ok, forget about the term implied, I want to ask what does it mean "symbol probability" here, I can understand a probability of a symbol for an specific use, for example, in a language, every letter on english has a different probability ok, but how is it defined a probability just over symbols when no particular use is defined? It seems that definition suppose coding is efficiently defined so longer symbols are less probable? How can I see it in an example for prefix codes?